# Run-Time Error 1004 - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add data validation to one of the columns. I have used the same code earlier and its working fine. But i am not sure why this is not working.

Following is my code:

```
Sheets("Input").Range("N:N").Select
  'Columns("N:N").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE((SUBSTITUTE(Y1, ""/"", """")), ""&"", """")), "" "", """")), ""("", """")), "")"", """")), "","", """"))"
//This where my code gives me an error stating Run-time error 1004
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
        Range("N1").Select
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
            :=xlBetween
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
```

Y1 cell in my excel sheet is a formula again. Would that be a problem?

Y1 cell sample values are : "Adult Cloting & ShoesPackaging/Labelling", "Jewelry, Watches, HandbagsRecall Inquiry/Regulatory Visit"

Comment: Take that huge formula and see if you can get it working on the worksheet first.

Comment: @Qharr Morning! that's what i said. (its marked within the code)

Comment: Probably a good idea to include some example strings that you are hoping to process and expected outcome as that formula has a lot of "" in it. You may have somewhere got the wrong number especially when escaping the character itself.

Comment: I will add the example string in the question and the formula is working on it own.

Comment: You remove all non-letter chars from the string in Y1 and you pass the remaining string to `INDIRECT`. However, `INDIRECT` expects a cell reference, not a value.